# IBM x3850 m2 megaraid not showing physical drives

Tags: hard-drive, bios, raid, hardware-raid

I have this IBM x3850 m2 with 2 physical drives installed but when I go to megaraid it doesn't show any of the physical drives

So I can't build a virtual drive to install the OS

***What I have tried so far***

1. I also made sure all cables are tight by opening it the panel
2. Tested individual drives I have verified that the drives are good by installing them in another machine
3. Even when plugging to x3850 I see that sas controller light up to confirm that power is reaching the sas controller even individual led for drives light up for few seconds
4. Searched around Google IBM forums but I can't find similar reference

**Questions**

- What could I try to fix this issue?
- Any way to bypass raid controller or raid configuration so as to have drives connected like just any desktop

Comment: Which drives (make/model) are you trying to use?  Have these (or ANY) drives ever worked in that system (that you've seen)?

Comment: One drive is seagate savvio st9146802ss

Comment: Second one Fujitsu enterprise mbb2147rc